# Custom Preference Center and Upsertdata for Data Extension

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I am working on a preference center and looking to use the `Upsertdata` to populate/ or update records in a data extension. The code is rendering fine in cloud pages but is not actually pulling in. records on submit. Is there something I'm missing in the code? Thanks for your help!
The data extension fields are (`First Name, Last Name, EmailAddress, PMOSH, OMSA, PMML, OMSACyber, PMASE`)

```
<script runat="server" type="text/javascript">
Platform.Load("core","1"); 
try {
</script>
%%[

var @Contact, @ContactRow, @FirstName, @LastName, @EmailAddress, @PMOSH, @PMASE, @PMML, @OMSA, @OMSACyber, @Status, @message, @subKey, @ErrorMessage, @isSubmitted

Set @Message = Concat(@Message, "email: ", @EmailAddress)

IF RequestParameter("isPosted") == "true" THEN   

   /* update Preferences DE and All Subscribers table */

    set @PMOSH = RequestParameter("PMOSH")
    set @PMASE = RequestParameter("PMASE")
    set @PMML = RequestParameter("PMML")
    set @OMSA = RequestParameter("OMSA")
    set @OMSACyber = RequestParameter("OMSACyber")
    set @subKey = RequestParameter('sKey')
    set @isSubmitted = RequestParameter("IsSubmitted")
    set @Unsubscribe = RequestParameter("Unsubscribe")

    UpsertData("Master_List_DE",1,"EmailAddress",@EmailAddress, "PMOSH", @PMOSH, "PMASE", @PMASE, "PMML", @PMML, "OMSA", @OMSA, "OMSACyber", @OMSACyber)    

    Set @Message = Concat(@Message, "Updated preferences for", @Email_Address, "!")
    Set @SuccessMessage = "Updated preferences!"

Endif 

/* update SFMC All Subscribers Status field. Subscriber will be added if they are not already there */

set @sub = CreateObject("Subscriber")
SetObjectProperty(@sub,"SubscriberKey", @subscriberKey)
SetObjectProperty(@sub,"Status", "Unsubscribed")

Set @options = CreateObject("UpdateOptions")
Set @save = CreateObject("SaveOption")
SetObjectProperty(@save,"SaveAction","UpdateAdd")
SetObjectProperty(@save,"PropertyName","*")
AddObjectArrayItem(@options,"SaveOptions", @save)

Set @statusCode = InvokeUpdate(@sub, @statusMsg, @update_sub_errorcode, @options)

if @statusCode != "OK" then
    set @error = "All subscribers not updated."
Endif

]%%
<script type="text/javascript" runat="server">
}
catch (e) {
  Write("<br>e: " + e);
}
</script>

<form id="TestPref" action="?" method="POST" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
    <div style="display: flex;">
      <div id="Level2LeftRightSide" style="width: 100%; display: inline-block;">
        <div id="TransCommFreqHeading" style="background-color: lightgray">
          <h4 style="color: black; padding-top: 5px; padding-bottom: 7px; position: center; text-align: center">
            <input type="checkbox" name="PMOSH" value="%%=v(@PMOSH)=%%"="" %%=Iif(@PMOSH=="true", "checked", "")=%% onchange="this.value=this.checked">PMOSH<br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="PMASE" value="%%=v(@PMASE)=%%"="" %%=Iif(@PMASE=="true", "checked", "")=%% onchange="this.value=this.checked">PMASE<br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="PMML" value="%%=v(@PMML)=%%"="" %%=Iif(@PMML=="true", "checked", "")=%% onchange="this.value=this.checked">PMML<br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="OMSA" value="%%=v(@OMSA)=%%"="" %%=Iif(@OMSA=="true", "checked", "")=%% onchange="this.value=this.checked">OMSA<br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="OMSACyber" value="%%=v(@OMSACyber)=%%"="" %%=Iif(@OMSACyber=="true", "checked", "")=%% onchange="this.value=this.checked">OMSACyber<br>
            <div style="text-align: center;">
                <input type="submit" class="buttonstyles" style=" font-size: 16px; font-family: Arial; color: #FFFFFF; text-align: center; text-decoration: none; background-color: #5D5D5D; border: 1px solid #5D5D5D; padding: 10px; border-radius: 3px; -moz-border-radius: 3px; -webkit-border-radius: 3px;">
            </div>
        </h4>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: You've got some curly quotes in your form and also some malformed HTML, e.g.: `name="PMOSH” value=" %%=v(@PMOSH)=%%"=""`

Comment: And please take the time to format and indent your code block before posting.  It'll help us help you.

Comment: @AdamSpriggs Thank you for pointing that out. Also noted about the format and I will make sure to do that before posting. I did update the code but I'm still not getting any results... is this correct URL format in terms of how to test the page (https://pub.s6.exacttarget.com/cb51jghrugr?skey=maurice.blackledge@gmail.com)

Comment: Please update your question with your latest code.  We don't really have enough info to investigate.

Comment: Done. Thanks for the help so far!